# Why is datetime(1970, 1, 1).timestamp() affected by timezone? (or, what is "timezone naive"?)

Tags: python, datetime

datetime object in Python is timezone naive by default. I was thinking this means if you construct a datetime object as below, you would always get 0 (but not):

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime(1970, 1, 1).timestamp())
# -32400.0 on my machine
```

As you can see, the datetime-naive object `datetime(1970, 1, 1)` is clearly affected by my local timezone.

So, what do "timezone naive" and "timezone aware" actually mean? I feel I'm missing something very basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timezone naive objects don't mean that they aren't affected by the timezone, just that they don't have enough information to distinguish where that time refers to. From this [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), it says:

> A naive object does not contain enough information to unambiguously locate itself relative to other date/time objects. Whether a naive object represents Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), local time, or time in some other timezone is purely up to the program, just like it’s up to the program whether a particular number represents metres, miles, or mass. Naive objects are easy to understand and to work with, at the cost of ignoring some aspects of reality.

This means that initializing the time can depend upon the timezone, but afterwards you won't be able to distinguish what timezone that came from. Timezone aware, on the other hand, you will be able to trace back to what timezone and what local reasons (day-light savings, etc) created that specific time so you can compare it to other timezone aware objects.